# failure with find() function using PHP with Silex

Tags: php, twig, silex

Here is the failure message I get in Terminal running 'phpunit tests':

1) StylistTest::test_find
null does not match expected type "object".

/Users/evanbutler/Desktop/hairSalonApp/tests/StylistTest.php:163

Here's my test method:

```
function test_find()
  {
    //Arrange
    $name = "Stylist Jane";
    $id = 1;
    $name2 = "Stylist Bob";
    $id2 = 2;
    $test_stylist = new Stylist($name, $id);
    $test_stylist->save();
    $test_stylist2 = new Stylist($name2, $id2);
    $test_stylist2->save();

    //Act
    $result = Stylist::find($test_stylist->getId());

    //Assert
    $this->assertEquals($test_stylist, $result);
  }
```

And here's my method:

```
static function find($search_id)
  {
    $found_stylist = null;
    $stylists = Stylist::getAll();
    foreach($stylists as $stylist) {
      $stylist_id = $stylist->getId();
      if ($stylist_id == $search_id) {
        $found_styist = $stylist;
      }
    }
    return $found_stylist;
  }
```

Here's my getAll method:

```
static function getAll()
  {
    $returned_stylists = $GLOBALS['DB']->query("SELECT * FROM stylists;");
    $stylists = array();
    foreach($returned_stylists as $stylist) {
      $name = $stylist['name'];
      $id = $stylist['id'];
      $new_stylist = new Stylist($name, $id);
      array_push($stylists, $new_stylist);
    }
    return $stylists;
  }
```

If you'd like to see all my files here's the link to the git repository:
https://github.com/evanb2/hairSalonApp.git

I've been staring at this for way too long and I'm totally stumped.

Comment: How does `Stylist::getAll()` work? If it's static and global like that you might get cross contamination across tests.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$found_styist = $stylist;
```

to

```
$found_stylist = $stylist;
```

You need a better IDE man. Simple static analysis could tell you about the unused variable.

Comment: wow, that's annoying. thanks man appreciate it. What's an IDE?